# .NET 6 Web API - Validate JSON Request Body to generate uniform Error response

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I want to validate my JSON request body to provide a uniform error response.

Currently, if there is an invalid character in JSON Body, then I get,

[image]

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-5c7b8c1fc5a3a1226dde24ce151cc9a5-889d7f82a7a1e72f-00",
  "errors": {
    "$": [
      "'\"' is invalid after a property name. Expected a ':'. Path: $ | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 12."
    ]
  }
}
```

Where as my standard error response looks like,

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": "Missing required fields: FIELD1",
  "errorCode": "FIELDS_MISSING",
  "target": "ValidateFields",
  "innerError": "Somerror"
}
```

How can I return JSON validation in the uniform error response object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try below method to custom the validation result.

Add the ApiBehaviorOptions to custom the badrequest error.

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(o =>
{
    o.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = actionContext =>
    {

        List<Error> error = actionContext.ModelState
                    .Where(modelError => modelError.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                    .Select(modelError => new Error
                    {
                        ErrorField = modelError.Key,
                        ErrorDescription = modelError.Value.Errors.FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage
                    }).ToList();

        return new BadRequestObjectResult(error);
    };
});
```

The Error class:

```
 public class Error
    {
        public string ErrorField { get; set; }
        public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

Result:
[image]